# Mean including nan values

Tags: python, pandas, mean

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
GFG_dict = { '2019': [10,20,30,40],'2020': [20,30,40,50],'2021': [30, np.NaN, np.NaN, 60],'2022':[40,50,60,70]}
    
gfg = pd.DataFrame(GFG_dict)
    
gfg['mean1'] = gfg.mean(axis = 1)

gfg['mean2'] = gfg.loc[:,'2019':'2022'].sum(axis = 1)/4

gfg
```

I want to get the average as in column mean2.

How do I get the same result using: `.mean(axis =1)`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `mean2` you are doing the sum (which skips `nan` values) and then always dividing by 4 (which is the count **including** `nan`).

You can achieve this by doing a `fillna(0)` and then calculating the mean:

```py
gfg['mean1'] = gfg.fillna(0).mean(axis = 1)
```

> NOTE: this will not fill the `nan` values in your dataframe but only do it for the mean calculation, so your dataframe will not be modified